# Python numpy Quick Array Calculations to 2D Array (matrix)

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, truthtable

I have a use case where I have a set of several thousand coordinates, and I want to vectorize them and turn them into distances. I want to do this in such a way that I end up with a 2D array, effectively a matrix, that is n x n, giving me the norm between the input points. I know that I'll have a pile of zeros along the diagonal, and that's fine. I want to process it as quickly as reasonably possible.

Currently my method is to take a numpy array of coordinates x,y,z is a row and the list is however many elements are loaded from a file, for instance 5000 rows.

I'm currently just looping through the list of coordinates as:

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        dist[i,j] = round(numpy.linalg.norm(coords[i] - coords[j]), 3)
```

dist is a numpy array setup with `numpy.zeros((n,n))` where I've already got the n value, being the length of the coords list.

I know there must be a faster way to use numpy on this dataset, making coords an array of course, I am just not sure how to do this efficiently. Part of the reason I want to do this is I intend to use a truth table mask against this for data processing. Thanks!

Comment: Seems like `pdist/cdist` - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution is as easy as mentioned above, just import scipy, and use:

```
distances = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(coords, coords)
```

The resulting array is the n by n array of the euclidean norms.

Answer (score 0):

another similar way to get the same answer from scipy:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

distances = squareform(pdist(coords))
```